# To check a color exist in cameraView in OpenCV for Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, colors

I am trying get a value true or false depends on if red color exist in the middle of the cameraView. In many examples, they are showing target color in white black colors, that's not I am looking for. I just want to make a toast like 'you are on the red color' when it appear on the screen. How can I do it?

I am new on that job so this is what I did so far :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2, View.OnTouchListener{
private CameraBridgeViewBase cameraManager;
private BaseLoaderCallback callBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        cameraManager.enableView();
    }
};
Mat mRgba;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_2_0, this, callBack);
    }

    cameraManager = (CameraBridgeViewBase)findViewById(R.id.kamera);
    cameraManager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cameraManager.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    cameraManager.setCameraIndex(0);






}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);

}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {

}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();






    return inputFrame.rgba();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    return false;
}
```

}

***Thanks a lot!***

Comment: and what is your question? you cannot expect an answer if you don't ask something. just formulating a problem and hoping that someone reads and or compiles your code hoping to find any possible issues and think of any question you might have is not going to work :) please read [ask]

Comment: @Piglet So how can I do that color alert thing :)

Comment: I'm sure you can think of the first thing you might have to do in order to achieve that. maybe you should try to do that. present some ideas at least. I don't want to think for you

Comment: @Piglet As you read, I am new on openCv library. So that means I have no experience with it, I never used and I know nothing about it. Of course I am not asking for think for me. I am asking for get a hint or a guide which you think it is useful for what I asked. If you have, please share with me, else you are wasting your time in that topic for nothing.

Comment: and did it cross your mind that it might be useful to do a beginners tutorial? your problem is that you want to much. you won't find an answer on how to trigger an alert when some color appers in the view. so break it down into small steps (this does not require any opencv knowledge btw). how do you read a pixel's color value for example. that would be necessary to solve that problem and you will find thousands of examples online. then extend it for a region of multiple pixels... step by step. I'm not trying to argue with you. I just want to make you understand how to solve something like that